# Is it possible to only get values of specific fields of MongoDB documents?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

For example, I have a collection of documents: `[{id:1, title:'A'}, {id:2, title:'B'}, ...]`

I want to fetch documents based on some conditions, and only get the values of the fields I want instead of the whole object. In SQL, this can be done by `SELECT title FROM documents WHERE year = 2020`

Can I achieve similar results in MongoDB with PyMongo?

Comment: The [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) method's **projection** parameter allows get values of specific fields. Here is PyMongo's [find](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method

Comment: Some examples at: [Project fields to return from query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Answer (score 0):

Try projection like this

```
$cursor = $db->inventory->find(
    ['status' => 'A'],
    ['projection' => ['item' => 1, 'status' => 1]]
);
```

Comment: The op is looking for a pymongo (python) solution. Yours looks like php.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` in MongoDB will have this syntax `.find(filter_part, projection_part)`, You can try below code in pymongo :

**Code :**

```
/** As `.find()` returns a cursor you can iterate on it to get values out,
 *  In projection `_id` is by default included, So we need to exclude it, projection can use True/False or 1/0 */

for eachDocument in collection.find({year : 2020}, {title: True, _id : False}):
      print(eachDocument)
```